# Problem with stereo rectification using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I am working on a stereo camera rig with 4 discrete cameras (of the same type) but at the moment only one pair (cam1 and cam2) are necessary. 
The aim is to calibrate the stereo pair and get 3D information about the scene. I am using Python 3.6 with OpenCV 3.4.3 in Visual Studio 2017.

I took 28 images of a chessboard calibration pattern and calibrated the cameras individually as well as stereoscopic with the standard OpenCV procedure. 
Since the calibration data seems good and the distortion correction is working fine, the next step is the rectification of the images.

This is where things become weird. I spent the last 3 weeks working on this and read a lot, tried a lot and always got crappy results. I used cv2.stereoCalibrate (also tried with different flags, as suggested in different topics), cv2.stereoRectify (also with different alpha values), cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap and cv2.remap for the actual remapping of the images (method 1). But the results are never as wanted.

I recently managed to get rectified images which look like they are actually rectified with cv2.uncalibratedRectification. Therefore I did not use matched points (since SURF and SIFT are unfree...) but a slightly different approach. The edges of the calibration pattern in my 28 calibration images are used as input points. This works good, but the rectified images don't look perfect.

Here are my images (these are no calibration images) so you can imagine what I'm talking about: 
[original left and right images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ZII.jpg) 
[undistorted images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzumD.jpg) 
[rectified with method 1, alpha=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQAtf.jpg) 
[rectified with method 1, alpha=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K6Gp.jpg) 
[rectified uncalibrated, best result I got by now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8mPE.jpg)

Can anybody give me a hint whats wrong with my usage of method 1? I've seen a lot posts to similar problems but I couldn't find the solution in the comments there. Or is this a bug in OpenCV?

Or has anyone an idea how to improve the uncalibrated rectification?

Here is a code snippet with the relevant calls:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import argparse
import sys
import os

# size calib array
numEdgeX = 10
numEdgeY = 7

# preface
exitCode = 0

# get directories
pathDir = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
pathDir = pathDir[:-17]
pathCalib = pathDir + "\\CalibData" + "\\chess"

try:
# define pair
p = 1
cal_path = pathCalib + "\\pair" + str(p)

images_right = glob.glob(cal_path + '\RIGHT/*.bmp')
images_left = glob.glob(cal_path + '\LEFT/*.bmp')
images_left.sort()
images_right.sort()

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TermCriteria_EPS +
                    cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
criteria_cal = (cv2.TermCriteria_EPS +
                    cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-5)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0); (1,0,0); ...; (6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((numEdgeX*numEdgeY, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:numEdgeX, 0:numEdgeY].T.reshape(-1, 2)

objpoints = []     # 3d points in real world space
imgpoints_l = []   # 2d points in image plane for calibration
imgpoints_r = []   # 2d points in image plane for calibration

for i, fname in enumerate(images_right):
        print(str(i+1) + " out of " + str(len(images_right)))
        img_l = cv2.imread(images_left[i])
        img_r = cv2.imread(images_right[i])

        # convert to cv2
        img_l = cv2.cvtColor(img_l, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_r = cv2.cvtColor(img_r, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # find the chess board corners
        ret_l, corners_l = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_l, (numEdgeX, numEdgeY), None)
        ret_r, corners_r = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_r, (numEdgeX, numEdgeY), None)

        objpoints.append(objp)

        if ret_l is True:
            print("image " + str(i+1) + "left - io")
            rt = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_l, corners_l, (11, 11),
                                  (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints_l.append(corners_l)

        if ret_r is True:
            print("image " + str(i+1) + "right - io")
            rt = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_r, corners_r, (11, 11),
                                  (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints_r.append(corners_r)

        # get shape
        img_shape = img_l.shape[::-1]


### CALIBRATION ###
# calibrate left camera
rt, M1, d1, r1, t1 = cv2.calibrateCamera(
objpoints, imgpoints_l, img_shape, None, None)

# calibrate right camera
rt, M2, d2, r2, t2 = cv2.calibrateCamera(
objpoints, imgpoints_r, img_shape, None, None)

# stereo calibration
flags = (cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5 + cv2.CALIB_FIX_K6)

stereocalib_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER +
                    cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 100, 1e-5)

#flags = 0
#flags = cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO
#flags = cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC   
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_K1...6
#flags = cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL
#flags = cv2.CALIB_THIN_PRISM_MODEL
#flags = cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH
#flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_S1_S2_S3_S4

flags = (cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT | cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO | cv2.CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH |
         cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3 | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K4 | cv2.CALIB_FIX_K5 |
         cv2.CALIB_FIX_K6)

T = np.zeros((3, 1), dtype=np.float64)
R = np.eye(3, dtype=np.float64)

ret, M1, d1, M2, d2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
        objpoints, imgpoints_l,
        imgpoints_r, M1, d1, M2,
        d2, img_shape,
        criteria = stereocalib_criteria,
        flags=flags)

# get new optimal camera matrix
newCamMtx1, roi1 = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(M1, d1, img_shape, 0, img_shape)
newCamMtx2, roi2 = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(M2, d2, img_shape, 0, img_shape)

# rectification and undistortion maps which can be used directly to correct the stereo pair
(rectification_l, rectification_r, projection_l,
    projection_r, disparityToDepthMap, ROI_l, ROI_r) = cv2.stereoRectify(
        M1, d1, M2, d2, img_shape, R, T,
        None, None, None, None, None,
        #cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,                  # principal points of each camera have the same pixel coordinates in rect views
        alpha=0)                                   # alpha=1 no pixels lost, alpha=0 pixels lost

leftMapX, leftMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    M1, d1, rectification_l, projection_l,
    img_shape, cv2.CV_32FC1)
rightMapX, rightMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    M2, d2, rectification_r, projection_r,
    img_shape, cv2.CV_32FC1)

### UNCALIBRATED RECTIFICATION ###
imgpoints_l_undis = []
imgpoints_r_undis = []

for i, fname in enumerate(images_right):
    img_l = cv2.imread(images_left[i])
    img_r = cv2.imread(images_right[i])

    # convert to cv2
    img_l = cv2.cvtColor(img_l, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_r = cv2.cvtColor(img_r, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # undistort
    img_l_undis = cv2.undistort(img_l, M1, d1, None, newCamMtx1)
    img_r_undis = cv2.undistort(img_r, M2, d2, None, newCamMtx2)

    # find the chess board corners in undistorted image
    ret_l_undis, corners_l_undis = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_l_undis, (numEdgeX, numEdgeY), None)
    ret_r_undis, corners_r_undis = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_r_undis, (numEdgeX, numEdgeY), None)

    if ret_l_undis is True:
        rt = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_l_undis, corners_l_undis, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        for j in range(0, len(rt)):
            x = rt[j][0,:]
            imgpoints_l_undis.append(x)

        if ret_r_undis is True:
            rt = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_r_undis, corners_r_undis, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            for j in range(0, len(rt)):
                x = rt[j][0,:]
                imgpoints_r_undis.append(x)

# convert to np array
imgpoints_l_undis = np.array(imgpoints_l_undis)
imgpoints_r_undis = np.array(imgpoints_r_undis)

# compute rectification uncalibrated
ret, uncRectMtx1, uncRectMtx2 = cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(imgpoints_l_undis, imgpoints_r_undis, F, img_shape)

### REMAPPING ###
# load images and convert to cv2 format
img_l = cv2.imread(images_left[0])
img_l = cv2.cvtColor(img_l, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_l_undis = cv2.undistort(img_l, M1, d1, None, newCamMtx1)
img_r = cv2.imread(images_right[0])
img_r = cv2.cvtColor(img_r, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_r_undis = cv2.undistort(img_r, M2, d2, None, newCamMtx2)

# remap
imglCalRect = cv2.remap(img_l, leftMapX, leftMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
imgrCalRect = cv2.remap(img_r, rightMapX, rightMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
numpyHorizontalCalibRect = np.hstack((imglCalRect, imgrCalRect))

# warp for uncalibrated rectification
imglUncalRect = cv2.warpPerspective(img_l_undis, uncRectMtx1, img_shape)
imgrUncalRect = cv2.warpPerspective(img_r_undis, uncRectMtx2, img_shape)
numpyHorizontalUncalibRect = np.hstack((imglUncalRect, imgrUncalRect))    

### SHOW RESULTS ###
# calculate point arrays for epipolar lines
lineThickness = 5
lineColor = [0, 255, 0]
numLines = 20
interv = round(img_shape[0] / numLines)
x1 = np.zeros((numLines, 1))
y1 = np.zeros((numLines, 1))
x2 = np.full((numLines, 1), (3*img_shape[1]))
y2 = np.zeros((numLines, 1))
for jj in range(0, numLines):
    y1[jj] = jj * interv
y2 = y1

for jj in range(0, numLines):
        cv2.line(numpyHorizontalCalibRect, (x1[jj], y1[jj]), (x2[jj], y2[jj]),
                 lineColor, lineThickness)
        cv2.line(numpyHorizontalUncalibRect, (x1[jj], y1[jj]), (x2[jj], y2[jj]),
                 lineColor, lineThickness)
cv2.namedWindow("calibRect", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("uncalibRect", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("calibRect", numpyHorizontalCalibRect)
cv2.imshow("uncalibRect", numpyHorizontalUncalibRect)
cv2.waitKey()


except (IOError, ValueError):
print("An I/O error or a ValueError occurred")
except:
print("An unexpected error occurred")
raise
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!
The issue was that OpenCV interpreted my images as a vertical stereo system, I just looked at it as it was horizontal.

Comment: How did you specify the Horizontal stereo flag in the stereoRectify function of OpenCV?